# Can there be a single limit of agreement value in Bland-Altman analysis?

Tags: agreement-statistics, bland-altman-plot

While trying to learn Bland-Altman analysis, I came across a situation that confused me a bit. I can understand upper (mean + 2 SD) and lower limits (mean – 2 SD), but a single limit of agreement (LOA) value is reported in an article.
"The 95% limits of agreement (LOA) of the "x value" between "a method" and "c method" was 93.02%. It was 90.81% between the "b method" and "c method"
Can there be such a single LOA value?

Comment: Is it possible for you to link to the article? My guess is that they mean the percentage of data points within the 95% LOA but it is hard to tell without context.

Comment: @wz-billings I figure out. Exactly, it is like you said, but I don't know how true it is reported in this way.